# Swift 3 delete nodes from singly linked list

Tags: swift, linked-list

I am trying to remove all elements from a linked list of integers that have value val. Is it necessary to set the removed nodes to nil to free memory?

```
func removeElements(_ head: Node?, _ val: Int) -> Node? {
    var first = head
    var current = head
    var prev: Node?
    while current != nil {
        if current?.val != val {
            prev = current
        } else if current?.val == first?.val {
            var oldFirst = first
            first = current?.next
            oldFirst = nil // is this line necessary?
        } else {
            prev?.next = current?.next // do I need to set current to nil?
        }
        current = current?.next
    }
    return first
}
```

Comment: You don't need `oldFirst` here. It's a local variable that does nothing. But this code isn't correct. It modifies the list in a surprising way and returns a different list. For example, given the list 1-2-3-1, if you remove "1" then the list becomes 1-2-3, but returns 2-3. You should either modify the list you're passed, or you should return a new list, but you shouldn't do both in different ways. (Note that this would normally be a method on `Node` rather than a free function in Swift.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oldFirst = nil` only sets the variable in your current scope to nil.
Again, `current` is a variable in your local scope, it gets already dereferenced and thus cleaned up once you leave its scope.

If you have no strong references to an object anymore it is released by itself because Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting)

I am not sure why you have the 2nd case in your code. I guess it checks the case where the current node has value `val` but you compare to `first.val` instead of `val`

Comment: Thank you Simon. You made a clear explanation. I set the 2nd case to check if the first node's val equals the target val. Sorry that my code was unorganized and misleading. I modified it as 
       ` if first?.val == val {
            first = first?.next
        } else if current?.val != val {
            prev = current
        } else {
            prev?.next = current?.next
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeElements(_ head: ListNode?, _ val: Int) -> ListNode? {
    guard head != nil else {
        return nil
    }

    let preDummy = ListNode(val: 0), postDummy = ListNode(val: 0)
    var pre = preDummy, node = head

    while node != nil {
        if node!.val == val {
            postDummy.next = node?.next
            node!.next = nil
        } else {
            pre.next = node
            pre = node!
        }
        node = node!.next
    }

    pre.next = postDummy.next

    return preDummy.next
}
```